# ArrayIndexOutOFBoundsException in a List Android

Tags: android, list, exception

I have an ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException

```
private Size getPictureSize() {
    List<Size> list = camera.getParameters().getSupportedPictureSizes();
        int i = 0;
    for (Size size : list) {
        if (Math.min(size.width, size.height) <= 800) {
            if (Math.max(size.width, size.height) > 800) {
                return size;
            } else {

                return (i > 0 ? list.get(i - 1) : list.get(0));
            }
        }
        i++;

    }

    return list.get(0);
}
```

This is part an application someone asked me to test after he put it on the market and one of the error report was this one at line

```
return (i > 0 ? list.get(i - 1) : list.get(0));
```

I know what this exception means but what could cause it?

Comment: Add the full Stack-Trace... as always.

Comment: Break that `return (i > 0 ? list.get(i - 1) : list.get(0));` into an if/else to see which *get()* is causing it.

Answer (score 1):

You have a couple of problems in your code:

- this line: `return (i > 0 ? list.get(i - 1) : list.get(0));` may calculate an index that does not exist in your list;
- the last line of your code (`return list.get(0);`) may raise an `IndexOutOfBoundsException` if your list is empty.

I changed your code to fix these problems. See if it solves your problem:

```
private Size getPictureSize() {
    List<Size> list = camera.getParameters().getSupportedPictureSizes();
    Size prevSize = null;
    for (Size size : list) {
        if (Math.min(size.width, size.height) <= 800) {
            if (Math.max(size.width, size.height) > 800) {
                return size;
            } else {
                return (prevSize == null? size : prevSize);
            }
        }
        prevSize = size;
    }

    if(list.size() > 0) {
        return list.get(0);
    }

    return null;
}
```

Comment: Ok so since this is an error which was reported on the Market I don't know for sure in which situations this happened and on what devices. Since there was just one report I assume this happened one time. The application worked fine on the devices on which he tested so now he asked me to find the issue and resolve it. Now is the question : How can I test your code if I don't know in which situation or on what device this error occured? And getSupportedPictureSizes says ' This method will always return a list with at least one element'. Is that even true? PS I will post the stack trace.

Comment: BTW  isn't prevSize always null? You initialized it but you never used it then you have the ternary operator where you check if it is null then size is returned else prevSize is returned. It doesn't make sense to me but I really don't have experience so if you omitted something please tell me.(or if I made a mistake understanding it)

Comment: Thank you for your help I think this error was marked as old and can;t give you the stacktrace anymore, but because I'm the kind of person who writes down everything the stacktrace I saw on the market showed the error on line 71 in getPictureSize() that would be the line with the ternary operator. I'm just interested on why this happened just once  and as I said in my previous comment I would like to understand the code you wrote.

Comment: As you can see, the line: "prevSize = size;" is responsible for assigning this variable. So prevSize is not always null. It's the same behavior of your code, but it avoids an index out of bounds exception, since it doesn't access some index.